# How to show places on google map?

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-maps-api-3

My iterator has 4 values i.e. mumbai, thane, nagpur, pune.

I want to show these values on my Google map.

I have an iterator for these values. but in JavaScript I am able to get only first value i.e. mumbai.

My question is: how can I show these values on Google maps after clicking particular button?

```
 function initialize()
        {
            var address = document.getElementById("ven").value;


            //alert(address);


            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                var location = results[0].geometry.location;

                var lat = location.lat();
                var long = location.lng();
                // alert('LAT: ' + lat + ' LANG: ' + long);


                var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
                var mapProp = {
                    center: myCenter,
                    zoom: 5,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myCenter,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                });

                marker.setMap(map);
            });

        }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('show'), 'click', initialize);
```

```html
<%@ include file="jshome.jsp" %>

    <section class="container">
        <div class="login">
            <s:if test="%{jfList.isEmpty()}">
                <h1>Sorry!!Currently no job fairs are there..</h1>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <h1>All Job Fairs</h1>
                <s:iterator value="jfList">
                    <table cellspacing="10">
                        <tr >
                            <td><b>Title</b></td>
                            <td><s:property value="title"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Message</b></td>
                            <td><s:property value="message"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Event Date</b></td>
                            <td><s:property value="date"/></td>
<!--                                <td><s:label name="date" label="Event Date "/></td>-->
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Venue</b></td>
                            <td><s:property value="venue" /></td>
                            <s:hidden id="ven" name="venue" label="Venue "/>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Recruiters</b></td>
                            <td><s:property value="recruiters"/></td>
<!--                                <td><s:label   name="recruiters" label="Recruiters "/></td>-->
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input  id="show" type="button" value="Show Map" onclick="initialize();"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </table>
                </s:iterator>
            </s:else>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. 
For example show rendered HTML instead of JSP if you have a JavaScript question. The JSP seems to have no bearing on your Google Map question. Also PLEASE refrain from using unnecessary punctuation. In English we use ONE full stop at the end of a sentence, a space and then a capital letter at the beginning of the next. Also the personal pronoun `I` is always capitalised.

Comment: PS: You have TWO onclicks - one inline and one added with the google event listener

Comment: yeah, but that is not the problem i am facing....i want to display those places after i click show map button..suppose i clicked on nagpur so nagpur should get displayed on map..

Comment: I understand your problem, but your code needs to be in such a way we can fix it without having to run a jsp container

Comment: ohk sir, actually i am new here..this my first post..i apologize for posting in a wrong way....but plz help me in this..

Comment: Fix your code as I described in my first comment an we will take a look

Comment: Also your first problem is IDs need to be UNIQUE!

Answer (score 0):

1. You have TWO onclicks, one inline and one created by the `event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('show'), 'click', initialize);`
2. you need UNIQUE IDs, so you cannot use `document.getElementById("ven")`

give the field a unique ID:

```
 <s:hidden id="UniqueID" name="venue" label="Venue "/>
```

and use the same in the button:

```
<input  class="show" type="button" value="Show Map" onclick="initialize('UniqueID');">
```

then you can do

```
funtion initialize(id) {
 var address = document.getElementById(id).value;
```

Comment: according to TLD we cannot give any expression to id attribute

Comment: According to TLD what? - anyway, creat your own IDs somehow. I have not use JSP for years - my examples can be changed to work with the framework you use. Your question is NOT JSP related as already said

Comment: now m able to get that 4 values..now the problem is how can i give unique id to button..means by clicking 1st button mumbai will get displayed..2nd button nagpur etc..

Comment: <s:hidden id="place" name="venue" /> by doing this that button is getting particular value.but javascript is getting only 1st value.

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Comment: <s:hidden id="place" name="venue" /> see i have putted this hidden tag along with my input button tag. so now, my button is getting a particular value like india for 1st button and america for 2nd. but javascript is taking only 1st value i.e.india

Comment: the ID is still not unique. I cannot see why your hidden tag would change anything unless you give it a unique ID and pass that ID in the click like I show you

Comment: i hav tried hard but not able to assign dynamic id.